# Get Xml Data Cross-Domain with JQuery

Tags: jquery, ajax, cross-domain

Is there a way to load XML Data Cross-Domain with JQuery (= client side)?

```
$.get('http://otherdomain.com/data.xml', function(xml) { }
```

The above doesn't work - do I have to rely on JSONP, or is there a way to load XML?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use **[JSONP](http://remysharp.com/2007/10/08/what-is-jsonp/)**.

Comment: Hmm, thought as much, too bad. Maybe there's still hope, I'll leave the question unanswered for a few hours. Thanks.

Comment: An alternate method is using a hidden xdomain iframe and communicating with it via `postMessage` and `receiveMessage`, but jsonp is much easier.

Comment: yeah, problem is, there are still loads of webservices which provide data only as xml. I was trying to implement a "generic" method to receive data.

Answer (score 2):

No way to load XML. So yes, using "standard" xmlhttprequests you need JSONpadding.

If the server supports "[Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS)](http://www.w3.org/TR/access-control/)" you can easily receive
data from a foreign domain.
That means, you have to add a custom header into your XmlHttpRequest ('Origin') and the server
decides if it does allow the request or not.

Answer (score 0):

I have found that with Chrome some jsonp techniques don't work.

Either you choose json and get a cross domain error or jsonp and xml format is not recognized, as waiting for jsonp format.

So, the solution is to use Yahoo Query Language api to retrieve the data on all browsers without cross domain error.

There are lots of ways to call the link and play with the xml data.

I can't post the code I have, but you will easily find snippets on the web.

So you have to define your url to query yahoo api with encodeURI method. The getJSON method comes from jQuery and then you parse an array of text results with raw xml.

Answer (score -1):

Well we are easily can get data from some php functions like file_get_content and curl (as I Php/ROR dev ,other languages has the same functions). Using these functions we can get the xml data from foreign domain,

Now question is why we are not able to do the same thing when using AJAX,
As per my understanding  curl and file_get_content function  doesn't invoke  the http request and Ajax does.

In nutshell we can not load the xml data using AJAX.