# Calling a webservices with JQuery ... How can i make code Working

Tags: json, web-services, jquery

I try to calling a webservices with JQuery.
How can i make code bellow Working ?

> ```
>    function TEST() {
>               var curcode = "AFA";
>               var serviceURL = "http://www.webservicex.net/country.asmx/GetCountryByCurrencyCode";
>               var requestData = "{'CurrencyCode':'" + curcode + "'}"; 
>
>                 $.ajax({
>                           type: "POST",
>                           contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
>                           url: serviceURL,
>                           data: requestData,
>                           dataType: 'json',
>                           success: function(msg)
>                                   {
>                                         var response = msg.d;  
>                                     alert("response.Message : " + response.Message);
>                                   },
>                           error: function(msg)
>                                {
>                                   alert("error msg : " + msg.d);
>                                  }    
>               });
>                   }
>  </script>
> ```

What did i miss ?

Regards,
Andrian

Comment: What exactly doesn't work? What error messages are you getting?

Comment: What does the server-side end look like?

Comment: the allert did not returning the Country information or alwawys return error message.... any idea ?

Comment: @ANDRIN:Share your webservice code

Comment: I use free webservices sample at my test code....

Comment: Just a side note it's more handy to use console.log() and, it give you  something like ´[2, 3, 4]´ not ´[object Object]´. When logging a object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your error is something like

`XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://www.webservicex.net/country.asmx/GetCountryByCurrencyCode. Origin <Your URL> is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.`

Than I hope is caused by the [CORS](http://www.w3.org/TR/cors/) [restriction](http://www.w3.org/TR/cors/#access-control-allow-origin-response-header).

If the service does not support CORS, the only way to consume this service at the client-side is to use a proxy at your server.

More resources if you're interested.

http://enable-cors.org/

[CORS on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/http_access_control)

[Using CORS @ html5rocks.com](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/cors/) by Monsur Hossain

[NEW TRICKS IN XMLHTTPREQUEST2](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/xhr2/) by Eric Bidelman

Comment: My error return ===> "undefined"

Comment: @ANDRIN Try opening your Firebug/Developer Console to see the actual error. 
You're seeing undefined in the alert because whatever you get in `msg` is actually the ajax `Object` which does not have a `d` key.

Comment: My firefox Web Developer Console return : [15:03:57.939] OPTIONS http://www.webservicex.net/country.asmx/GetCountryByCurrencyCode [HTTP/1.1 200 OK 265ms]

Comment: @ANDRIN I think you're confusing. The [HTTP OPTIONS](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html#sec9.2) method is for a different purpose, used by the browsers internally. What you are trying to do is a POST. If you are on Firefox, please install Firebug and check the console tab of the Firebug panel to find the actual error.

Comment: i did not touch everything about HTTP OPTIONS... where is comes from ?

Comment: this is my firebug  console tab return:
"Reload to activate window console"
"enabling javascript debugger to support console"
reference to undefined property e.queue
[Break On This Error] }),f.extend({clone:function(a,b,c){var...nstall-button a.button","click")})}();

Comment: preloa...70857f6 (line 3)
reference to undefined property elementArr.nodeType
[Break On This Error] if(elementArr && elementArr.nodeType == 3)
inspector.js (line 60)
<System>
reference to undefined property f.event.triggered
[Break On This Error] a){var b=F.exec(a);b&&(b[1]=(b[1]||"")...,this)});if(arguments.length){var a=f
jquery....min.js (line 3)

Comment: reference to undefined property d.headers
[Break On This Error] .clean(arguments);a.push.apply(a,this....y",[],function(){return f})})(window);
jquery....min.js (line 4)
reference to undefined property msg.d
[Break On This Error] alert("error msg : " + msg.d);
jQuery1.htm (line 27)

Comment: @ANDRIN The error I posted was from Chrome Developer Tools -> Console.

Comment: anyway.. thank' sujay for your kindly help.. my problem solved (see above solution provide by Stone)

Comment: @ANDRIN 
Open this [fiddle](
http://jsfiddle.net/LeWWx/1/) and take a look at your console. It should tell you that the request was rejected. I'm not sure why Firefox does not throw an error on the CORS policy violation.
XDomainRequest is IE's CORS support.

Answer (score 0):

Try visiting: http://www.webservicex.net/country.asmx/GetCountryByCurrencyCode?CurrencyCode=AFA

The returned data's format is xml. So I think you should use xml format in your ajax calling instead.

**EDIT**

Okay, I managed to make it work with the help of a [jquery plugin](https://github.com/padolsey/jQuery-Plugins/tree/master/cross-domain-ajax/).

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.xdomainajax.js"></script>
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
     $.ajax({
         url: 'http://www.webservicex.net/country.asmx/GetCountryByCurrencyCode?CurrencyCode=AFA',
         type: 'GET',
        success: function(res) {
            alert(res.responseText);
        }
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
</body> 
</html>
```

Give it a try.

Comment: that's what i allready did... see ---> var requestData = "{'CurrencyCode':'" + curcode + "'}";

Comment: change  dataType from json to xml did not affect anything ... still same error

Comment: @ANDRIN Then I think unfortunately the answer might be 'no' there is no easy way to retrieve cross-domain xml data with jquery ajax. See a similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/2942673

Comment: I'd also guess it has something to do with cross-domain... thank's  for your link i will discover more...

Comment: @ANDRIN See my edited answer. It's working now, though the retrieved data needs some parsing.

Comment: not sure if this will help, but we use http handlers in-between our clients and web services, this allows us to serialise to JSON which is more light weight and can be parsed directly to an object in the JQuery code.

Comment: @Stone yes... finaly it's work... thank's you're briliant....

Comment: @ANDRIN Glad to help! Since mission is complete, you can accept my answer to help me earn enough reputation to help more people...

Comment: This doesn't seem to work with all URLs. For example, this one didn't work even though it also returns XML: http://www.webservicex.net/geoipservice.asmx/GetGeoIPContext